# Do MySql transactions block other transactions?

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have a few Transactions that will be trying to update the same column at the same time, but before that, a validation will occur to check if the column value is more or equal than 5. If true, the column will be updated to the current value - 3.

My question is, are SQL transactions treated like a queue or are they accessing the column as soon as the transactions starts? will transactions mess with each other?

LIKE:
Column Value = 5.
Transaction 1: validates true
Transaction 2: comes in and validates true
Transaction 1: updates to column value -3 (=2)
Transaction 2: updates to column value -3 (= -1)

OR
Column Value = 5.
Transaction 1: validates true
Transaction 2: comes in but has to wait in the queue...
Transaction 1: updates to column value -3 (=2)
Transaction 2: validates false
Transaction 2: Done

I've been searching for an answer with no success, but if you see it has already been answered, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Transactions are made by queue. When a transaction start : 1 - The database is lock for others queries update/insert to prevent changes until the transaction is not finished. 2 - Queries are not registered until a commit was not send.

Comment: A transaction blocks things until it is committed or rolled back. For an in-depth explanation of transaction the [MySQL reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) would be a good place to start.

Comment: @Shim-Sao, thanks a lot! By your answer, I assume a SELECT (only) transaction would be possible, right?

Comment: Thanks @Dave. I'll look into it.

Comment: Don't confound : Query and Transaction. A TRANSACTION (keyword) is a bunch of queries that you can commit and rollback (if something "wrong" happen on the process). A Query can be made without any transaction. You can SELECT all the time, but if a SELECT is made before the COMMIT, so you will have data before transaction validation.

Comment: If you just do select, no need of transactions. If you are updating and inserting on multiple table and you don't want only half of the data to be changed if a bug occur until the end of the proscess, use transaction(your bunch of queries)/commit/rollbak

Comment: @Shim-Sao, yes you're right, no need for transactions in SELECTS. And you just cleared another popping question, would a cross-table transaction work the same way? yes. Thanks once again.